Is it possible to use Folder.Files within Power Query Custom Connector?
I am writing a custom power bi connector and want it to find files in a specified folder.
eg: "Choose Folder" and then my connector goes off an loads some content in etc.
As soon as I try to use Folder.files, I get errors such as:
Credentials are required to connect to the MyCustomConnector source.
I have an auth block that looks like this:
    shared MyCustomConnector = [
        Authentication = [
            // Specify that this connector uses anonymous authentication
            Anonymous = []
        ],
        Label = "My Anonymous Connector"
    ];

But doesn't seem to make a difference.  There seem to be no docs on this.
